# Minecraft Bow Enchanting / Modding -> Infinity

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-hexxit

I wonder, why i cant get some enchantment on some bows I created myself in MInecraft Hexxit on some not. I already got, that it belongs to if they're already enchanted by modding or not (sort of Fortune or Loot with Lapis Lazuli). So now my question:

Is there ANY way to get an 'Infinity'- enchantment on Manyullyn- ,Steel or even one of the lower bows that I smeltered myself? I already searched for hours, but got no CLEAR answer.

Comment: Have you tried yourself?

Comment: ya? I tried via Enchanted Book and via Enchanting Table, but none of them worked, maybe I missed something?

Comment: Hold the bow in your hand and type: `/enchant <player> 51 <enchantment level>`. 51 is the id for the infinity enchantment. If this doesn't work it isn't possible.

Comment: That enchantment can't be added to that item. Thanks, would you post it as answer? Then I'll accept it.

Comment: @Ekonion It can, just not by the enchanting table. Check my answer for more information

Comment: @imulsion what answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot enchant those bows with the vanilla "Infinity" enchant. The command `/enchant <player> 51 <enchantment level>` does not work on those items, and neither do the normal methods of using an enchanting table or an enchanting book.